# Programmatically filter a list in C# using a variable number of criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I need to filter a list (which is randomly created when the application starts)  using a variable number of criteria defined by the users.

The list is a list of Tuples, as

```
List<(int, double)> list = new List<(int, double)>();
```

The `int` filed is any integer from 1 to 10, while the `double` filed is any double from 0 to 1000 (decimal precision down to 5 digits). This list can be as long as thousands entries (each tuple is unique).

The users have to possibility to define a maximum 20 filter criteria (with a maximum of 3 creteria for each integer), and they look like as follow:

```
List<(int, double, double)> criList = new List<(int, double, double)>();
```

The criteria in `criList` can be as simple as `1, 1.1, 55.1`, which means retain only those entries where the first filed is 1, and the second filed is between 1.1 and 55.1.

The criteria can also be a bit more complex:
`1, 1.1, 55.1` + `3, 0.1, 809.55` (keep entries with 1 in first field where the second field is between 1.1 and 55.1 OR entries with 3 in first field where the second filed is between 0.1 and 809.55)

`1, 1.1, 55.1` + `1, 100.1, 102.1` + `3, 0.1, 809.55` (keep entries with 1 in first field where the second field is between 1.1 and 55.1 OR between 101.1 and 102.1 OR entries with 3 in first field where the second filed is between 0.1 and 809.55).

As a first approach I thought to use a simple for loop to iterate over the `criList`, filter `list` for each criteria and append the result into a new list, but that is not very efficient right?

I then though to initialize a placeholder list as follow:

```
public class Criterion
{
    public int ValueInt;
    public double ValueMin;
    public double ValueMax;
}

List<Criterion> placeholderList = new List<Criterion>();

// just for the sake of this example, I can do this in a much better way :)
placeholderList.Add(new Criterion{ValueInt= 1, ValueMin = -1.0, ValueMax= -1.0}); //criterion 1
placeholderList.Add(new Criterion{ValueInt= 1, ValueMin = -1.0, ValueMax= -1.0}); //criterion 2
placeholderList.Add(new Criterion{ValueInt= 1, ValueMin = -1.0, ValueMax= -1.0}); //criterion 3
placeholderList.Add(new Criterion{ValueInt= 2, ValueMin = -1.0, ValueMax= -1.0});
placeholderList.Add(new Criterion{ValueInt= 2, ValueMin = -1.0, ValueMax= -1.0});
placeholderList.Add(new Criterion{ValueInt= 2, ValueMin = -1.0, ValueMax= -1.0});
placeholderList.Add(new Criterion{ValueInt= 3, ValueMin = -1.0, ValueMax= -1.0});
//more
placeholderList.Add(new Criterion{ValueInt= 10, ValueMin = -1.0, ValueMax= -1.0}); //criterion 30
//30 criteria in total, since max 10 are allowed, and max 3 for the same integer
```

Then I could update the `ValueMin` and `ValueMax` of `placeholderList` by looping over `criList` to get the user defined values, and then use a big LINQ to filter `list` like

```
list.Where(/* criterion 1*/ || /* criterion 2*/ || /* criterion 3*/ || /* ... */)
```

but it looks odd to write this big LINQ.

Any suggestion on how I can make this filtering efficient and, very important, as fast as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it easy as:

```
list = list
    .Where(t => criList.Any(t2 => t.Item1 == t2.Item1 && t.Item2 >= t2.Item2 && t.Item1 <= t2.Item2))
    .ToList();
```

The `Any` is the translation of your `OR` requirement.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks! Still learning